# windows mobile 6.5 backlight event disconnects socket

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm developing a windows 6.5 mobile application for a warehouse. I'm connecting to a server through TCP, and everything works fine until backlight goes off. 
Even when I'm not sending anything, socket.IO exception is thrown (client side aborts the connection) and my server application removes the client from the pool.

My project requires to handle clients that connect for long periods of time (usually 8 working hours). Is there any way of detecting that event ? 
I'm using c# windows forms and .net 3.5

(I just remembered about this.LostFocus property, but it does not work as expected).

@EDIT

In the end I solved it by disposing the socket and reconnecting. If someone will be in need to detect it, just do this: (not the cleanest, but works)

```
try
 {
// let it crash
 sthfailed = pollfailed = Form1.clientSocket.Client.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectError);
}
catch (SocketException u)
                {
                    progress++;}
try
{    //this is the easiest way, let it crash n detect it
     if (Form1.clientSocket.Client.Available == 0)
                        ;
}
catch (Exception h)
{ progress++; }   //if both 'try' blocks have failed its probably due to power state
```

and confirming with  a bool variable set up when powerstate changes

`OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.PowerManagement.PowerDown += new        DeviceNotification(PowerManagement_PowerDown);`

Comment: Just reconnect.  You should never rely on 100% connectivity with a wireless, battery-powered mobile device.  Stuff happens, just build in the ability to reconnect and retry your operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These mobile devices try to save power to extend battery live. There are different PowerStates from "full on" to "full off" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932261.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930499.aspx). The OEM can define which devices will be powered within which PowerState.

I see different possible solutions:

1. avoid the device changing the power state and set a PowerRequirement from code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms920689.aspx
2. change the battery idle timeouts and (possibly available) power settings for different devices. You may set PowerRequirement to "full on", but handle an idle period from code and lower the backlight.
3. Change the registry to set the device power state for the network device to not enter Suspend when the System Power State enters Suspend state. You can map device power states to system power states using the registry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920052.aspx
4. Make your app "system power state aware" and close/reopen the socket when device suspends/resumes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919833.aspx. I used this approach in a serial port to keyboard wedge application.

see also BatteryLog at http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/12/07/windows-mobile-some-logging-tools/ to get an idea what the system does when changing the power states.

there maybe more solutions...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply. 2 3 and 4 make a lot of sense, but the 3rd seems to be most suitable for me. I'll give it a go and select the answer once im done..